# Как представить это в шаблонизаторе blade

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Привет.

Нужно перенести логику с php в blade.

```
if(isset($var)){
    if($var == 1){
        echo '1';
    }else{
        echo '0';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Подробнее.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#control-structures)

```
@isset($var)
    @if($var == 1)
        1
    @else
        0
    @endif
@endisset
```

> Версия 5.0 не имеет блока `@isset()`

Comment: Такой вариант не работает

Comment: @Shillkas что пишет в ошибке?

Comment: http://joxi.net/zANevaXUleDb82 - это фреймворк laravel

Comment: @Shillkas возможно у вас старая версия ларавеля

Comment: По-моему версия 5.0

Comment: @Shillkas да, в этой версии этого блока ещё нету. Измените на `@if(isset($var)) ... @endif`

Comment: `@if(isset($auth_status))
 @if($auth_status == 1)
        1
    @else
        0
    @endif
@endif` Сделал так и все работает. Спасибо, а то я новичок в laravel

Comment: Да да, все работает